# Creating slices within for loop

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy. My basic understanding of it is that you want to achieve efficiency by applying operations to arrays, as this moves the `for` loops into c code. I'm trying to make the `calc` function below more efficient, and therefore applied this principle by using slices and `x1-x2`. This removed the internal `for` loop I initially had in my code and gave a large performance boost. Is there anything else I can do to make the function more efficient or would I need to implement it in C instead?

```
import math
import numpy as np
import time

def calc(x, i, K, N):
    r = np.empty(K)
    r[0] = 0
    for k in range(1, K):
        o = math.floor((k + N) / 2)
        x1 = x[i-o:i-o+N]
        x2 = x[i-o+k:i-o+N+k]
        s = np.square(x1-x2)
        r[k] = np.sum(s)/len(s)
    return r

input = np.arange(8, 10, 0.002) * np.sin(np.arange(0, 100, 0.1) * np.pi)

start_time = time.time()
output1 = calc(input, 500, 64, 448)
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Outputs:

0.00018095970153808594

This was my first attempt:

```
def calc(x, i, K, N):   
    r = np.zeros(K)
    s = np.zeros(N)
    for k in range(1, K):
        o = math.floor((k + N) / 2)
        for n in range(N):
            s[n] = x[n - o + i] - x[n - o + i + k]
        s = np.square(s)
        r[k] = np.sum(s) / len(s)
    return r
```

Outputs:

0.0051839351654052734

Comment: Is this your accelerated code? can you show what is the slow version, so its clearer what you are doing?

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: @Ander Biguri Added original

Comment: 0.1ms for that seems quite fast to me for numpy actually

Comment: Does my solution answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a way to speed up you calc function, however all the code in total would run way faster if you import your libraries in the following way:

```
from math import floor
from numpy import empty, square, sum, arange, sin, pi
import time

def calc(x, i, K, N):
    r = empty(K)
    r[0] = 0
    for k in range(1, K):
        o = floor((k + N) / 2)
        x1 = x[i-o:i-o+N]
        x2 = x[i-o+k:i-o+N+k]
        s = square(x1-x2)
        r[k] = sum(s)/len(s)
    return r

input = arange(8, 10, 0.002) * sin(arange(0, 100, 0.1) * pi)

start_time = time.time()
output1 = calc(input, 500, 64, 448)
print(time.time()-start_time)
```

But maybe that's just not what your looking for.

Comment: How do you justify the claim that it's 'way faster'? I get a difference of 4us which equates to about 1%

Comment: I don't mean that the calc function would be faster (I couldn't find a way), but your entire code (specificly your import statements) could be faster. Because instead of importing the whole library you could just import the functions you need and that would make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to vectorize the code by creating arrays of `x1` and `x2` based on a sliding window view of `x`, computed using [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view). But remember, there is always a tradeoff between speed and readability.

```py
import math
import numpy as np

def calc(x, i, K, N):
    r = np.empty(K)
    r[0] = 0
    for k in range(1, K):
        o = math.floor((k + N) / 2)
        x1 = x[i-o:i-o+N]
        x2 = x[i-o+k:i-o+N+k]
        s = np.square(x1-x2)
        r[k] = np.sum(s)/len(s)
    return r

def calc2(x, i, K, N):
    r = np.zeros(K)
    k = np.arange(1, K)
    o = (k + N)//2
    a = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(x, N)
    x1 = a[i-o]
    x2 = a[i-o+k]
    s = (x1 - x2)**2
    r[1:] = np.sum(s, axis=1)/N
    return r

arr_in = np.arange(8, 10, 0.002) * np.sin(np.arange(0, 100, 0.1) * np.pi)
```

Comparison:

```py
%timeit calc(arr_in, 500, 64, 448)
466 µs ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit calc2(arr_in, 500, 64, 448)
102 µs ± 2.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

If you'll be calling your function many times, using numba might be a good option. You can apply it to your original double-loop and it will be even faster than my vectorized version above. The fastest seems to be using the single `for` loop version.

```py
@njit
def calc3(x, i, K, N):   
    r = np.zeros(K)
    s = np.zeros(N)
    for k in range(1, K):
        o = (k+N)//2
        for n in range(N):
            s[n] = x[n - o + i] - x[n - o + i + k]
        s = np.square(s)
        r[k] = np.sum(s)/N
    return r

@njit
def calc4(x, i, K, N):
    r = np.zeros(K)
    for k in range(1, K):
        o = (k + N)//2
        x1 = x[i-o:i-o+N]
        x2 = x[i-o+k:i-o+N+k]
        s = np.square(x1-x2)
        r[k] = np.sum(s)/N
    return r

calc3(arr_in, 500, 64, 448)
calc4(arr_in, 500, 64, 448)
```

Timings:

```py
%timeit calc3(arr_in, 500, 64, 448)
69.1 µs ± 466 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%timeit calc4(arr_in, 500, 64, 448)
38.9 µs ± 54.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: The sliding window view version doesn't give the same results as the original function, for example with ```i, K, N = 5, 37, 57```

Comment: @Nin17 I'm not sure what to compare it to since your version is returning all 0s for those values.

Comment: I don't have a version, I'm just pointing out that there are inputs for which the sliding window view version provides a non nan answer whereas the original code is just nans and inputs where the sliding window code will raise errors when the original code returns

Comment: @Nin17 For the `i, K, N` you just gave, your version (i.e. the original) does not produce a result. Do you have an example where the original version produces a result but min doesn't?

Comment: ```calc```, ```calc2``` and ```calc3``` all give different results with the ```i, K, N``` I just gave

Comment: @Nin17 I get a division by 0.

Comment: yeah in calc, but not in calc2 or calc3 and their results are different

Comment: You wrote `calc`/`calc4` and `calc3`. I don't know what the original problem is to say which function gives the correct result. I was just working with what you gave. Since `calc` doesn't work for that input, I cannot tell you what the "right" answer is for that input.

Comment: no I didn't I'm not OP I'm simply stating that your code doesn't give the same results as the original functions for all inputs

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't paying attention so I thought you were. My bad. OP wrote those functions, so I can only go off what they gave. I don't know if that combination of `i, K, N` is even a valid input for their application.

Comment: Note that for `i, K, N = 5, 37, 57`, `i-o = -24`, so I don't think that input would be valid. I'm assuming OP intended for them to all be positive indices.